# Convert the result of a Google BigQuery query to valid GeoJSON

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gis, geojson

I have this query:

```
SELECT ST_BOUNDARY(ST_UNION_AGG(ST_SIMPLIFY(geo.polygon,5000))) as feature,
   zr.region_id
   from `tl_2019_us_zcta510_geom` geo
INNER JOIN `zip-regions` zr
ON geo.ZCTA5CE10 = zr.zip5
GROUP BY zr.region_id
```

The result is that `feature` is a `GEOGRAPHY` type.

---

Now, all I want to do is get the result in complete valid GeoJSON format.

I have tried playing with `ST_TOGEOJSON` like so:

```
SELECT ST_TOGEOJSON(ST_BOUNDARY(ST_UNION_AGG(ST_SIMPLIFY(geo.polygon,5000)))) as feature,
   zr.region_id
   from `tl_2019_us_zcta510_geom` geo
INNER JOIN `zip-regions` zr
ON geo.ZCTA5CE10 = zr.zip5
GROUP BY zr.region_id
```

...but that gives me each feature as GeoJSON.

My question is: If BigQuery can create a GeoJSON output line by line, can it then extend that to giving me my entire output as one valid GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 1):

First, that query result is not quite 'each feature as GeoJson'. You get each geography as GeoJson, but feature in GeoJson has special formatting - geography should be a field called `geometry`, and all other properties like `region_id` in your case should be nested inside a field called `properties`.

So you need following transformations:

- nest all additional properties into `properties` field,
- create `Feature` object per row,
- add `properties` and `geomerties` fields to the `Feature` object.
- add top level `FeatureCollection` object (if you want "normal" GeoJson, rather than new-line-delimited-GeoJson format)

BigQuery cannot do this natively, it is very simple to do, e.g. here is a short `node.js` code that performs this transformation on new-line-delimited-JSON files produced by BigQuery:

https://github.com/mentin/geoscripts/tree/master/bq2geojson